# Edit manually (using notepad etc) existing connections' names in SQL Developer Connections pane

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have over 150 database connection names in my SQL Developer connections tab. And now I have to change all due to naming convention change (for my ease of understanding). 
Is there a way of editing the connection names (the names with which we store the connection detail) externally using notepad etc ?  Or, is it that I have to open up "properties" for each one and change manually in each case. The new names will follow a pattern as did the old ones.

Comment: try exporting the connections to a .xml file, edit it using notepad++ or any other editor. Then import again.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on Connections and select Export Connections. That will give you an XML file you can edit. Then right click Connections again and select Import Connections. If you change the name, it may import the connections as new ones, rather than renaming them (I'm not sure), so you may wind up with duplicates that need deleting.

Comment: The connections are already in a file, connections.xml..just edit that directly with SQLDev CLOSED.

Comment: Even better! (Extra characters added to meet the minimum for a comment.)

Comment: Also, in version 18.3 and higher, it's not XML, it's JSON.